# AucTeX on Android?

Tags: texlive, emacs, auctex, android

How hard is it to get AucTeX (LaTeX + Emacs) set up on an Android device?  Right now that's the biggest hurdle to me considering buying a tablet (I'd get one of those covers with a built-in keyboard—can't do without a keyboard).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might be more appropriate for the [Emacs beta](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) site? At least, figuring out how to set up Emacs and AucTeX seems more appropriate for that site, whereas asking how to set up a TeX distro on Android might be appropriate for this site. But it seems like you're asking the former.